# How DNS cache clears in dnsmasq

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ubuntu-16.04, dnsmasq

Does dns cache clears after the max-cache-ttl seconds even if receives negative response from the parent name server which defined in resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq..?

```
# Server Configuration
listen-address=127.0.0.1
port=53
bind-interfaces
user=dnsmasq
group=dnsmasq
pid-file=/var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid

# Name resolution options
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
cache-size=1000
neg-ttl=2
max-cache-ttl=5
domain-needed
bogus-priv

cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search eu-west-1.compute.internal
```

My domain resolves fine with @127.0.0.1 and not resolves with the parent name server in resolv.dnsmasq. So is it resolving from cache..? In that case I have max-cache-ttl as 5 seconds so does it maintain the cache if the parent name server provides negative response..?

The domain I am trying to dig ends with rds.amazonaws.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A negative response is also cached... (with its own TTL which should be the zone SOA minimum value)

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the comment. By using neg-ttl, I know the neg response is cached, however if I cache the neg response, I at least should get a DNS error, but I never have any issue with DNS resolution from 127.0.0.1 for any domain name but none of them resolves with the parent name server I have defined it on the resolv.dnsmasq.